# Sqlite: single query with 2 different COUNT not using UNION

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, count, union

I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE "questions" 
("counter" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , 
 "questionid" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
 "chapter" INTEGER NOT NULL ,  
 "image" VARCHAR NOT NULL )
```

I want to get this:

```
CHAPTER, NUMBER OF QUESTIONS IN CHAPTER, NUMBER OF IMAGES IN CHAPTER
```

I managed to get the results with a UNION, but this does not follow my requirements above (i.e. I have an output of 2 columns, not 3 columns)!

```
// First query: get only chapters with images, and count all questions
SELECT Q1.chapter as "chapterID with images", count(q1.image) as c1
FROM questions AS Q1
where q1.chapter IN (SELECT chapter from questions where image NOT LIKE "")
group by q1.chapter

UNION

// Second query: get only chapters with images and count only images
SELECT Q2.chapter as "chapterID with images", count(q2.image) as c2
FROM questions AS Q2
WHERE Q2.image NOT LIKE ""
group by q2.chapter
```

Trying with a single query I only get either the first COUNT or the second, for example as follows.

```
// NOT WORKING!
SELECT Q1.chapter as "chapterID with images", count(q1.image), count (q2.image)
FROM questions AS Q1, questions AS Q2
where q1.chapter IN (SELECT chapter from questions where IMAGE NOT LIKE "")
AND q1.counter= q2.counter
group by q1.chapter
```

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

Following the approach suggested by LS_dev, I solved as follows.

I would like now to get the values from the 2 subqueries and divide them (i.e. images/questions), but it doesn't work, however I know this is a different question...

```
SELECT chapter,     
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions WHERE chapter=Q1.Chapter AND image NOT LIKE "" ) as  "number of images",
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions WHERE chapter=Q1.Chapter) as "number of questions"
FROM questions AS Q1
WHERE chapter in (SELECT chapter from questions where IMAGE NOT LIKE "")
GROUP BY chapter
```

Comment: `UNION` always add rows. `JOIN` add columns, but is not suited for your problem.

Comment: I know, yes, but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That problem is best suited for sub-queries, as different counts are needed:

```
 SELECT chapter, COUNT(),
    (SELECT COUNT() FROM questions WHERE chapter=q1.Chapter AND image NOT LIKE "")
    FROM question AS q1 GROUP BY chapter;
```

EDIT: To allow some more manipulations:

```
CREATE VIEW sums_view AS SELECT chapter, COUNT() AS question_count,
    (SELECT COUNT() FROM questions WHERE chapter=q1.Chapter AND image NOT LIKE "") AS image_count
    FROM question AS q1 GROUP BY chapter;
```

Now, previous query may be used as a table:

```
 SELECT * FROM sums;
```

And some mora manipulation may be done:

```
 SELECT *, image_count*100.0/question_count AS image_ratio FROM sums_view;
```

Comment: Thanks, do you maybe know how to get the values from the 2 subqueries and divide them (i.e. images/questions)?

Comment: For such you'd better create a view and them manipulate it. I will add it to answer.

Comment: I noticed now a mistake. I'll make some correction and tunning.

Comment: I missed `GROUP BY`, which made first sub-query unneeded.